# Extjs 4 window hide or destroy

Tags: window, extjs4, hide

[image]

Hi,

I'm implementing a layout with Extjs 4 as shown in the image.

The layout contains

1. 4 tab panels
2. Each tab content will be loaded dynamically. The loaded page contains `left navigation panel` and `right side container` to load the respective page
3. The page which is loaded in right side container will have a button
4. When the button is clicked a pop will be shown

I'm showing one pop up in page1 and another different pop up in page2.

What my problem is

when i click the button on the 1st page its showing a popup (say pop up 1),
for the second page when i click on the button it has to show pop up2, which contains some panels.

But pop up 1 appears in the second page.

the same pop up appears in all the sub pages.

if i reload the entire page and directly go to the page2 it shows the pop2.

i think that the window once created will persist until the page is reloaded.

i'm using window as follows

```
var createLessonWin = Ext.widget('window', {
    autoHeight:true,
    id: 'cformWin',
    closeAction: 'hide',
    y: 100,
    modal: true,
    plain: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: profile_form

});



Ext.get('add_lessons_btn').on('click', function () {
        createLessonWin.show();

    });
```

if i use `closeAction: 'destroy'` window elements also destroyed.

i tried with `Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {})` and new `Ext.Window also`. the same problem appears.

Content of the pop up in each page is a different form

How to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you only use that code for one of the two windows. The `items` property is what goes in the window, so you'll need that to be different for the two buttons. Secondly, make sure your `id`s are unique for each window.

If you post some more code, I might have a better idea of what's going on. How do you create your other window?

Comment: Thanks @David Kanarek for you quick replay. i updated the question. Please check it. I'm creating the other windows same as above, button ids and windows names and windows content will differ in each page

Comment: By window name, do you mean the window's id property or the variable in which you store it? Is there some reason you don't want to simply recreate the window each time the button is clicked?

Comment: Great guess Mr. David Kanarek. While copy and pasting the window code, i forgot to change the id value of window. that caused the problem. Now i solved it by giving unique id to each window.Thanks for your great help.

Comment: Whats the better way to create and use ext elements. 1). Write a function that creates a window and call the function whenever required. or 2). write the window code in Ext.onReady() and use the window for subsequent actions using hide and show.  With the second way i'm facing issues with the id's which i have explained above..

Comment: You don't need to, and probably shouldn't, give ids to all components. You're better off putting them in variables (`var win = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', ...)`) or finding them later with Ext.ComponentQuery